# what are the ways to create web App that will execute shell script smoothly

Tags: php

I am trying to build an web interface to execute the shell script on the linux environment.

I tried the same using the PHP `shell_exec("test.sh")` but it did not work properly. It is unable to execute few commands on the **test.sh** file and if i try executing the test.sh file it works properly though linux terminal.

```
<?php
   shell_exec(command);
?>
```

I just want to execute shell script through web interface , language can be any(Php, Java, nodejs..)

Comment: Could you specify what "did not work properly" means exactly ? What command doesn't work and what error do you get ?

Comment: It says the command not found.. This command is mentioned on the test.sh file and it work properly when I directly execute the test.sh file.. The command is a binary file name which is in some other location but defined in the bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

Share more information for a better answer, by the way, it's probably caused by users permissions. When you run a command with `shell_exec()` the user running it is `www-data`.